# How can I write a SELECT query with starting row of particular PK?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, pagination, paging

I'm using MySQL, which support OFFSET and LIMIT, it's great.
But what if I want query with first row equal to particular primary key instead of page index?

e.g. I have a table:

```
ID NAME   HEIGHT
1  kevin  1.67
2  bob    1.82
3  jane   1.70
4  wayne  1.59
```

I want a list of people order by their height ASC with first page's last ID is 1, the whole view is 4 1 3 2 (page size = 2)

Something should like:

```
SELECT ID,NAME,HEIGHT FROM table OFFSET ???? LIMIT 2 ORDER BY HEIGHT ASC
```

So I should get:

```
3 jane 1.70
2 bob  1.82
```

Comment: Pretty sure `ORDER BY` needs to come **before** `OFFSET` and `LIMIT`. In any case, your offset is just the page number multiplied by the page size (-1 to account for the zero-based offset)

Comment: You shouldn't use `id` for anything but getting a specific row (or to make sort order stable due to it being a unique key).  The values are unimportant, and rarely relevant.  If you're attempting to push down criteria (so in theory you don't need the `OFFSET`), your `WHERE` clause would need to look something like `WHERE height > :previousHeight OR (height = :previousHeight AND id > :previousId)` (this assumes that `id` has been added to the `ORDER BY` to make ordering of identical `height` values stable, we don't actually care what its value is).

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse thx for the advice, my problem with it is that my client just request 'load more' action and gives me the last ID at bottom of the list, it's pretty much like loading comments on Youtube, everytime I got last comment's ID, How can I implement this?

Comment: The problem is `id` is meaningless, because you're ordering by `height`.  You'd have to do a lookup based on the given record (probably simplest by a self-join to the table), then use that, in which case `OFFSET` should be `0`.  Are you sure he's not passing you an index?  Youtube (and similar) can get away with a simple `id` because the value would most likely be generated in the usual sort order - by when the comment was made.  That's not the case for you here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the solution.
The request has to include both `id` and a sorting factor (in my case it's `height`). so that the query would look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (t.height = last_height AND t.id > last_id) OR t.height > last_height ORDER BY t.height ASC, t.id ASC LIMIT 2
```

In case there are multiple people with the same height, the `id` can be used to pin-point the starting row.

Many thanks to Clockwork-Muse for lighting the bulb!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

**Logic :**

```
page_size  page_number    OFFSET
   2          1         (2*1)-1 = 1
   2          2         (2*2)-1 = 3
   2          3         (2*3)-1 = 5
```

**Query :**

```
SELECT ID,NAME,HEIGHT 
FROM table 
ORDER BY HEIGHT ASC, ID ASC 
LIMIT 2 OFFSET (page_size * page_number)-1
```

Comment: You need to add a unique column to the `ORDER BY`, to ensure a stable sort order (unique keys are good for this, and one of the few times they belong in that clause).

Comment: The logic is right here, what if I don't have a `page_number` available?

Comment: You have to learn pagination in PHP check link http://www.phpeasycode.com/showdemo.php?target=/pagination/demo.php